# Difference between not exists and not in

Tags: oracle, plsql

Please somebody explain why

```
select count(*) from employees where employee_id not in (select manager_id from employees)
```

returns 0

when clearly there are some employees who are managers also.

I am using HR schema.

Comment: `manager_id` and `employee_id` are two completely different keys, they most likely have different values.

Comment: There is an employee without a manager_id in your table (the CEO?), so your subquery contains a NULL value, which causes the 0. Here is why: http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/02/25/not-in/

Comment: @RobvanWijk That's a valid point!

Comment: @RobvanWijk You should post that as an answer. Lots of people don't understand how `not in` works when there are `null`s in the set.

Answer (score 1):

based on the query i would suggest you to use 
    NOT EXISTS as it gives BOOLEAN result which boosts up the performance.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM employees
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT employee_id
  FROM employees
  WHERE type = 'manager' -- or however you differentiate
    -- employees and managers
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this it looks like you're trying to link the `employee_id` with the `manager_id`, which are probably different.

Instead you could query for matching employee_id values for managers, using some other criteria to identify managers in the employees table.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM employees
 WHERE employee_id NOT IN
 (
      SELECT employee_id
      FROM employees
      WHERE type = 'manager'    -- or however you differentiate
                                -- employees and managers 
 )
```